# Is it necessary to keep vinaigrette in refrigerator?

Tags: food-safety, refrigerator, salad-dressing

I made vinaigrette which is composed of red wine vinegar, olive oil, salt, and sugar. Does this need to be refrigerated, or is it safe to leave it out of the fridge?

Answer (score -1):

None of the listed ingredients require refrigeration so you are safe to leave the vinaigrette at room temperature as long as it's not fluctuating much. Leave it in a cool, somewhat shaded area (out of direct sunlight if possible). If you wanted, you could absolutely leave your vinaigrette in the fridge.

Comment: -1 for implying that if each ingredient is shelf stable on its own, the mixture will also be shelf stable. This is one of the more dangerous myths in food safety.

Comment: Source, please?

Comment: @StevenXavier Flags are not for contacting moderators to ask them to reply to a comment; you can @-reply to rumtscho directly here if you wish (though I *think* she'd have been notified without it because she was the only person who commented before you).